# Why would memcached refuse to store data with some keys?

Tags: python, ubuntu, memcached

I use the memcache extension for python, and I have a very strange problem. Memcached refuses to store the exact same data with some keys, and succeeds in caching some others.

```
>>> import memcache
>>> conn = memcache.Client('121.0.0.1:11211', debug=0)
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d2', 'test');
True
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d3', 'test');
0
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d4', 'test');
True
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d5', 'test');
0
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d6', 'test');
True
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d7', 'test');
0
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d8', 'test');
True
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d9', 'test');
True
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591e0', 'test');
True
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591e1', 'test');
True
```

I don't really understand. I should add that I use the version 1.40 of the memcache module with memcached 1.2.8 running on Ubuntu Server 9.10. I restarted the memcached daemon, same result, with the same keys.

Thanks.

**Update:** I upgraded memcached to version 1.4.2, packaged on lucid repos, with the exact same result.

**Update #2:** The exact same commands entered on another server with a fresh ubuntu setup gives the same result, same places.

**Update #3** As suggested, with a list instead of a string in the Client insantiation :

```
>>> import memcache
>>> conn = memcache.Client(['121.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d2', 'test');
0
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d3', 'test');
0
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d4', 'test');
0
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d5', 'test');
0
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d6', 'test');
0
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d7', 'test');
0
>>> 
>>> conn = memcache.Client('121.0.0.1:11211', debug=0)
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d2', 'test');
True
>>> conn.set('138b9c95d693760840aab85ee5591d3', 'test');
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first param should be a list

```
conn = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
```

Comment: Hum. Yep.
But I'm afraid it's getting worse with a list, which I can't explain. I can't get it to work.

See my update #3

Comment: Are you sure your memcached is running? Try with `debug=1`

Comment: Hum... Yes, it is. But I feel pretty stupid now, as I typed 121 instead of 127 in the IP address...
And it works now.
Now, I don't understand why it did work...
Thanks, by the way.

Comment: @Pierre, Of course it never was working...just a weird bug in the memcache module I think